# Is there a way to skip/throw-out/ignore records in Spark during a map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have a very standard Spark job which reads log files from s3 and then does some processing over them. Very basic Spark stuff...

```
val logs = sc.textFile(somePathTos3)
val mappedRows = logs.map(log => OurRowObject.parseLog(log.split("\t")))
val validRows = mappedRows.filter(log => log._1._1 != "ERROR")
...and continue processing
```

Where `OurRowObject.parseLine` takes the raw log line and maps it to some (key, value) pair (e.g. `( (1,2,3,4), (5,6,7) )` that we can then do processing on. Now, if `parseLine` encounters a "problem" log (malformed, empty, etc...) it will return some sentinel value (e.g. `( ("ERROR", ...), (...) )` which the filter step then filters out.

Now, what I have been trying to find a way to do is to simply not include the problem row(s) during the map...some way to tell spark "Hey this is an empty/malformed row, skip it and don't include a pair for it", instead of that additional filter step.

I have not yet been able to find a way to do this, and find it very interesting that this functionality does not (AFAICanFind) exist.

Thank you

Comment: Instead of during the `map`, you could add `.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")` or `.option("mode","FAILFAST")` to interrupt the job with a useful exception during the `textFile` read. [See the docs for more detail](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could make the parser return an Option[Value] instead of a Value. That way you could use flatMap to map the lines to rows and remove those that were invalid.

In rough lines something like this:

```
def parseLog(line:String):Option[Array[String]] = {
    val splitted = log.split("\t")
    if (validate(splitted)) Some(splitted) else None
}

val validRows = logs.flatMap(OurRowObject.parseLog(_))
```

Comment: While I really like this solution, it seems like you should be able to achieve a similar effect using the one parameter overload of `collect` (instead of `map` or `flatMap`) and a `PartialFunction`. I haven't been able to get anything more than a trivial example working but you may find it's also a fun possibility to explore. This `Option[Value]` approach seems a lot easier to use. (I'm happy to share my code but won't post it since it doesn't quite work.)

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov That's correct, `collect(PF[A,B])` should also work to do this kind of filtering. The one thing about `collect` is Spark that I don't like is that `collect` without params is to get all data to the  driver while `collect(PF)` is a transformation, which gets confusing for people. Could you add it as an answer? It's a very valid option.

Comment: @maasg I'm totally with you about the two overloads of collect being confusing. It's one of the weaker corners of the Spark APIs, in terms of design. I also find the mechanism for defining `PartialFunction`s in Scala to be a bit restrictive and hard to use. I'll see if I can fix my solution and post it: I'm having a problem with serializability of composed partial functions.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov if you want, put your code on a question to have a look. Regarding PF syntax, `{case x:Foo => something(x)}` is pretty ok, no?

Comment: @maasg Posted here, but it makes me a bit sad.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov an interesting approach. Didn't know that the compositions of Pfs is not serializable.

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to use the one-parameter overload of `collect` (instead of `map` or `flatMap`) and a `PartialFunction`. This is a little tricky if the partial function you need isn't completely trivial. In fact yours probably won't be because you need to parse *and* validate, which I'll model below with *two* partial functions (although the first one happens to be defined for all inputs).

```
// this doesn't really need to be a partial function but we'll 
// want to compose it with one and end up with a partial function
val split: PartialFunction[String, Array[String]] = {
  case log => log.split("\t")
}

// this really needs to be a partial function
val validate: PartialFunction[Array[String], Array[String]] = {
  case lines if lines.length > 2 => lines
}

val splitAndValidate = split andThen validate

val logs = sc.parallelize(Seq("a\tb", "u\tv\tw", "a", "x\ty\tz"), 4)

// only accept the logs with more than two entries
val validRows = logs.collect(splitAndValidate)
```

This is perfectly good Scala but it doesn't work because `splitAndValidate` isn't serializable and we're using Spark. (Note that `split` and `validate` are serializable: the problem lies with composition!) So, we need to make a `PartialFunction` that *is*  serializable:

```
class LogValidator extends PartialFunction[String, Array[String]] with Serializable {

  private val validate: PartialFunction[Array[String], Array[String]] = {
    case lines if lines.length > 2 => lines
  }

  override def apply(log: String) : Array[String] = {
    validate(log.split("\t"))
  }

  override def isDefinedAt(log: String) : Boolean = {
    validate.isDefinedAt(log.split("\t"))
  }

}
```

Then we can call

```
val validRows = logs.collect(new LogValidator())
```