# flatMap creates multiples lines in DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Based on previous SO answers:

- [Is there a way to skip/throw-out/ignore records in Spark during a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767032)
- [Spark - How to handle error case in RDD.map() method correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350187)

It seems that doing "map and filter out error cases" should be possible in a single operatoin using [flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=flatmap#pyspark.RDD.flatMap).

Given sample data:

```
spark.read.text("/mnt/seedx-ops-prod/genee-local-datasync/genee-3/genee/logs/genee_python-20190417T075453.005.log").show(4, False)

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2019-04-17 07:54:51.505: 2019-04-17 10:54:51 INFO [main.py:64] Read machine_conf.ini         |
|2019-04-17 07:54:52.271: 2019-04-17 10:54:52 INFO [app.py:93] Running web server on port 9090|
|2019-04-17 08:05:10.720: 2019-04-17 11:05:10 INFO [app.py:166] Exiting event loop...         |
|2019-04-17 08:05:10.720: <_WindowsSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I expect successful parsing for the first 3 lines, followed by a parse error that would not produce results for the 4th line.

```
def parseTheNonSuckingDaemonPythonLogs(row):
  try:
    parts = re.findall(r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{1,3}): (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) ([A-Za-z]{1,5}) (.*)', row.value)[0]
    return Row(os_ts=parts[0], log_ts=parts[1], log_level=parts[2], message=parts[3])
  except:
    return Row()
```

The expected result is

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
|os_ts                  |log_ts             |log_level|message                                    |
+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
|2019-04-17 07:54:51.505|2019-04-17 10:54:51|INFO     |[main.py:64] Read machine_conf.ini         |
|2019-04-17 07:54:52.271|2019-04-17 10:54:52|INFO     |[app.py:93] Running web server on port 9090|
|2019-04-17 08:05:10.720|2019-04-17 11:05:10|INFO     |[app.py:166] Exiting event loop...         |
+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
```

The actual results looks as following:

```
genee3_python_logs_text = spark.read.text("/mnt/seedx-ops-prod/genee-local-datasync/genee-3/genee/logs/genee_python-20190417T075453.005.log")

clean_genee3_python_logs = genee3_python_logs_text.rdd.flatMap(parseTheNonSuckingDaemonPythonLogs)

from pyspark.sql import Row

row = Row("val")
genee3_python_logs_df = clean_genee3_python_logs.map(row).toDF()
genee3_python_logs_df.select('*').show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------------------------+
|val                                        |
+-------------------------------------------+
|INFO                                       |
|2019-04-17 10:54:51                        |
|[main.py:64] Read machine_conf.ini         |
|2019-04-17 07:54:51.505                    |
|INFO                                       |
|2019-04-17 10:54:52                        |
|[app.py:93] Running web server on port 9090|
|2019-04-17 07:54:52.271                    |
|INFO                                       |
|2019-04-17 11:05:10                        |
|[app.py:166] Exiting event loop...         |
|2019-04-17 08:05:10.720                    |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to get it working, I'm still not sure about the functional transformations that help it be the case.

#### Wrap the Row in another Row inside the parsing logic:

```
def parseTheNonSuckingDaemonPythonLogs(row):
  try:
    parts = re.findall(r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{1,3}): (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) ([A-Za-z]{1,5}) (.*)', row.value)[0]
    return Row(Row(os_ts=parts[0], log_ts=parts[1], log_level=parts[2], message=parts[3]))
  except:
    return Row()
```

#### Drop the Row adaptation inside the DataFrame declaration:

```
genee3_python_logs_df = clean_genee3_python_logs.toDF()
```

#### Result:

```
genee3_python_logs_df.show(truncate=False)

+---------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|log_level|log_ts             |message                                    |os_ts                  |
+---------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|INFO     |2019-04-17 10:54:51|[main.py:64] Read machine_conf.ini         |2019-04-17 07:54:51.505|
|INFO     |2019-04-17 10:54:52|[app.py:93] Running web server on port 9090|2019-04-17 07:54:52.271|
|INFO     |2019-04-17 11:05:10|[app.py:166] Exiting event loop...         |2019-04-17 08:05:10.720|
+---------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```